# "{}" means array or 

Tags: objective-c

I'm readding "iphone programming-the big nerd ranch guide", and there is a snippet like this:

```
static NSString *randomNounList[3] =
{ 
    @"Bear", 
    @"Spork",
    @"Mac"
};
```

So `randomNounList` is now an array? But it is declared as `NSString`. What do braces `{}` mean here ?

Comment: It is not declared as NSString, the [] makes it an array (of NSString *)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's declared as an array of 3 pointers to `NSString`. Within `{}` you initialize the array.

Answer (score 2):

Was already answered, but here is a common way to initialize an array of *int*'s
that might help you to see what's happening:

```
int array[] = { 1,2,3 };
```

You don't even need the count, the compiler can figure it out.

I'd recommend you reading a learning a good bit of C so you can understand code
like this one (excerpt from the Bison manual):

```
#include <math.h>

...

struct init
{
  char const *fname;
  double (*fnct)(double);
};

struct init const arith_fncts[] =
{
  "sin", sin,
  "cos", cos,
  "atan", atan,
  "ln", log,
  "exp", exp,
  "sqrt", sqrt,
  0, 0
};
```

:-)